# (Windows Terminal) and xterm-mouse-mode has a problem

Tags: debugging, mouse, wsl

Don’t really know where to post this issue, or even the nature of it, but it can get very frustrating. This is not exclusive to Windows Terminal, MobaXTerm has the same problem.

So I use emacs under Windows Subsystem for Linux 2. Using the mouse works fine in most cases, but there are some elements which makes it completely freak out. I tried both on Spacemacs, and a clean emacs.d config. In Spacemacs, I can click on many links without problem, but when I click on a last opened file, it freaks out. It shows a bunch of `down-mouse1 ESC [ < 0 ; 1 1 1` in the command bar and every button or key I press will add on this list. There is no escape, I have to restart emacs. Another place this happens, which standard emacs shares, is `customize-group`. Clicking on search, a title works fine, but as soon as I click `Show Value` it freaks out again. I will add a gif to demonstrate how it works until it breaks (a bit cursor offset) [image]

Comment: Try to narrow down the cause. Try starting from `emacs -Q`, then adding only 1/2 of your init file, then 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc., to see which thing or things cause the problem. As it stands now, it looks like you have a big sack of stuff that you're using, and you're trying to figure out what's wrong. Divide and conquer.

Comment: And maybe try to give a specific, step-by-step recipe of what you do interactively and what the effect is. *"it freaks out"* and *"has a problem"* are not specifics that people can react to operationally.

Comment: Personally, I recommend using the Windows release of Emacs rather than running it inside WSL. However, you should be able to escape that broken input sequence by typing `C-g`; that should at least allow you to avoid restarting Emacs because of this.

Comment: Thank you @db48x C-g is a blessing. And you all have a point. I’m new to Emacs & Lisp in general, so I don’t know how to approach a debug. A clean config nor `emacs -Q -nw` changed anything. I too tried different `TERM` values. Using X11 does not cause this problem though. I may ask on Win Term or WSL github. What are those input codes called, which spawn in the bottom bar?

Comment: The terminal receives mouse events from the windowing system, and has to communicate them to whatever program is running inside. It does so by converting them into escape sequences. I don't think that these escape sequences were ever used by any real terminals, but they are reasonably well standardized these days. Emacs does generally know how to interpret them, so it's surprising that it fails in this manner. Since it still happens with -Q, I recommend filing a bug report (you can use `M-x report-emacs-bug`).